# Why does this mathematical pattern occurs here?

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic

The actual question goes like this

> A room has N (1 to N inclusive) bulbs and N switches. N people go in one   by one. 1st person goes in
>   and toggles none of the switches. 2nd person goes in and toggles all
>   switches other than the multiples of 2(2, 4, 6...). 3rd person goes in
>   and toggles all switches other than multiples of 3(3, 6, 9...), and so
>   on (Till Nth person toggles all the switches except Nth switch). Once
>   the process is finished, how many bulbs are in 'on' state. (Assume
>   that all bulbs to be in 'off' state initially).

The original question can be found [here](http://www.codechef.com/ABYN2015/problems/LUCBULB)

I tried solving it by writing a brute force solver first, but it would have given me a "time limit exceeded" verdict because N can be as large as 10E9 ,

While testing the solutions for some values of N, I hit upon a pattern which led to the final solution

It is best explained with a picture, observe the number of 1's which are separated by 0's - 2 , 4 , 6 , 8 ...

[image: python brute solver]

**But I am still unable to figure out why this pattern exists? In other words what is the mathematical reason behind this pattern?**

Here is the draw(N) code I used

```
def draw(N):
    arr=[0]*N
    for i in range(2,N+1):
        for j in range(0,N):
            if((j+1)%i!=0):
                arr[j]^=1
    print(N,arr)
    ans=0
    for i in range(0,N):
        if(arr[i]==1):
            ans+=1
    print(ans)
```

Comment: I am a little confused if this question belongs to SO or MO.

Comment: sometimes there's only a thin line between programming and maths .

Comment: @NamitSinha Definitely not MO.  I think you're thinking of math.SE.

Comment: Hint: How many times is switch m hit? Who hits it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a version of an [old puzzle](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/recreational-math/puzzles/brain-teasers/v/light-bulb-switching-brain-teaser). The usual version has the nth person flip the switches whose numbers are divisible by n, and that produces the same pattern of squares (the switches with square indices 1, 4, 9, 16 are toggled) whether N is even or odd. Here, exactly the opposite switches are toggled, which is equivalent to toggling all switches an extra N times, which does nothing if N is even, and reverses them when N is odd. You showed only cases where N is odd, which means the squares are the switches that don't change states.

Factors of a number come in pairs, except when the number is a square, since we can pair the factor x with n/x, and these are distinct except when x^2=n.

For example, 18 has 6 factors: 1 and 18, 2 and 9, and 3 and 6. So, if you toggle switch 18 once for each factor, it stays in its original state.

100 has 9 factors: 1 and 100, 2 and 50, 4 and 25, 5 and 20, and sqrt(100)=10. So, if you toggle switch 100 once for each factor, it changes states.

You mentioned the number of 1s between the 0s. (n+1)^2-n^2 = 2n+1. So, you are seeing 2, 4, 6, 8, etc. 1s between the 0s for N odd.

Comment: How do you get " (n+1)^2-n^2 " ?

Comment: It's just algebra to expand (n+1)^2 = n^2+2n+1, so you get 2n 1s followed by one 0. Do you mean why is that relevant? If the squares are the switches that are not toggled, then if one square is n^2, the next is (n+1)^2.

Comment: Can you please explain this statement a little more, " exactly the opposite switches are toggled, which is equivalent to toggling all switches an extra N times,". I understand how the only perfect squares are toggled, but not the latter part of your line.

Comment: @user3004790: Make sure you see the difference between this problem and the classical version. In the classical version, the first person toggles all switches, then the second person toggles all even switches, then the third person toggles all switches whose indices are divisible by 3. In this one, the first person toggles no switches. This is equivalent to toggling all switches, then toggling all switches. The second person toggles just the odd switches. That is equivalent to toggling the even switches and then toggling all switches, etc. The count the total number of toggles.

Comment: Every switch is toggled an extra N times compared with the original version of the puzzle. Instead of toggling a switch once for each factor of the index, the switch is toggled N times plus once for each factor of the index.

Answer (score 2):

Douglas Zare already explained the relationship to an older problem, so I'm just going to detail the solution to the older problem, whose sequence shows up in your image anyway.

I assume the switches are initially off (0), but the reasoning is the same regardless. The first person leaves them all off. The second person turns on `2 4 6 ...`. The one that will **obviously** stay on out of these is `2`, because according to the problem's rules, it will never be toggled again.

Then the third person toggles `3 6 9 ...`. Again, **obviously** `3` will stay on.

Then the fourth person toggles `4 8 12 ...`. **Obviously** `4` will stay off forever (it was turned on by the second guy).

Now we can tell (it might be more obvious if you go up to the 9th guy) that perfect squares will always be off and the rest will always be on. These statements require an explanation:

**1. Perfect squares will always be off**

A perfect square has an odd number of factors:

```
x^2 = (p_1^e_1 * ... * p_k^e_k)^2
    = p_1^2e_1 * ... * p_k^2e_k,  p_i prime
divisors(x^2) = (2e_1 + 1)(2e_2 + 1)...(2ek + 1) = odd
```

By the [number of divisors](http://mathschallenge.net/library/number/number_of_divisors) formula.

Since each number is toggled by its divisors, the perfect squares will always end up in the initial state, because they have an odd number of divisors.

**2. Numbers that aren't perfect squares will always be on**

This is because only perfect squares have an odd number of divisors, so the other numbers will always be in the opposite of the initial state.

Assume a non-perfect square has an odd number of divisors. Then:

```
divisors(x) = (e_1 + 1)...(ek + 1) = odd
=> all e_k are even
=> we can write the number as (p_1^(e_1 / 2) * ... * p_k^(e_k / 2))^2
=> x is a perfect square, a contradiction.
```

Then the efficient solution for the problem involves finding how many perfect squares are below `n`: there are `sqrt(n)` perfect squares below `n`, and these are `1, 2, ..., sqrt(n) - 1, sqrt(n)`.

Comment: You need to adjust for the differences between this problem and the classic version. The second person does not toggle 2, 4, 6, etc. The statements you start with "obviously" are not correct.

Comment: @DouglasZare - yes, but it's pretty much the same thing. If the initial state is `1` and you **don't** toggle `2 4 6 ...`, that's the same as if the initial state was `0` and you did toggle just those. My explanation addresses what can be seen in the OP's image.

Comment: It's not just the first two steps that are different. Your explanation is based on the classic version of the problem. In this one, instead of "obviously staying on" the switches in this version are toggled every later round.

Comment: @DouglasZare - the OP asked for an explanation of the pattern in the image he attached, which is what I addressed. He said that pattern led him to the solution for the initial problem but he wanted it explained. So I'm not sure why the versions are relevant, I answered what was asked...

Comment: The OP asked for an explanation for problem X, you described what happens in problem Y. You don't correctly explain the relationship between problem X and Y. The statements you make following the bold "obviously"s are wrong, and you don't state what happens for N even. That your statements are wrong and confusing to someone who doesn't know the classical puzzle but who has worked on the CodeChef problem is why the difference between the versions matter.

Comment: @DouglasZare - ok, I clarified that I'm addressing the other problem. You already mentioned the relationship, so I just referenced your answer in that regard.